# export Json file data into Excel Sheet in back end on Android

Tags: java, excel, pdf

I built an Android Application where i use Firebase Database.

All data show in RecyclerView.

I want to export it into Excel Sheet/pdf in local Storage.

Have any way to do this? Please Help.

[RecyclerView is Like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctJKL.jpg)

Comment: Any attempts? Maybe some code examples?

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far